# Every set with more than point admits a permutation with no fixed point and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Assuming axiom of choice , for any set  $S$ with more than one point , there exist a bijection $f:S \to S$ such that $f(s) \ne s , \forall s \in S$ . Is the converse true , i.e. Does the statement " For every  set  $S$ with more than one point , there exist a bijection $f:S \to S$ such that $f(s) \ne s , \forall s \in S$ " implies Axiom of Choice ? Or at least  can we prove that  any set with more than point has a permutation with no fixed point , without axiom of choice ? Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: My answer in the duplicate shows that it is much weaker than choice. It is not provable without choice, and there are threads here with such example, but I have to go and it will have to wait (or you can search for it yourself).

Comment: @AsafKaragila : I do not see any reference there of why "it is not provable without choice "

Comment: As I said, this is in a different question, and you can look for it yourself or wait until I am by a keyboard to do that for you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103161/is-there-an-element-with-no-fixed-point-and-of-infinite-order-in-operatorname/

Answer (score 0):

This statement allready follows from the addition theorem, which states that $A \times \{0,1\}$ is equipotent with $A$ for every infinite $A$ (as on $A \times \{0,1\}$, $(a,x) \mapsto (a, 1+x)$ is fixed-point-free). The addition theorem is known to be strictly weaker than the axiom of choice (a result by Sageev).

Comment: True it follows , but I didn't know that this is strictly weaker than axiom of choice , could you please give a reference ?

Comment: Sageev, G.: Notices Amer. Math. Soc. 20 (1973), A22.

Comment: The paper was fully published, in 180 painful pages of forcing in pre-Shoenfield times.